# Web API unit test case using Moq

Tags: c#, moq, webapi

I wrote the following code as Service of Web API in .Net 6:

```
public async Task<Foo1> GetFileByObjectId(int objectId)
{
    List<Foo2> selectedFoo2 = (await SelectFoo2(objectId)).ToList();
    if (selectedFoo2.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new HttpStatusException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, 22, $"The object doesn't exist.");
    }

    if (!IsAdmin)
    {
        List<Permission> permissions = (await _permissionService.Select(username)).ToList();
        if (permissions.Count == 0 || permissions.Count() == 0)
        {
            throw new HttpStatusException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, 23, $"The User {username} doesn't own the necessary rights");
        }
```

Now I wrote the following Unit Test using Moq to verify the case of missing permissions:

```
public async Task TestGetFileByObjectId()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock.Get(_permissionService).Setup(mock => mock.Select(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>(), string.Empty)).Returns(Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Repeat(Mock.Of<Permission>(), 0)));

    var configValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"AppSettings:RootFolder", "..."},
        };

    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddInMemoryCollection(configValues)
        .Build();

    Foo2Service myService = new Foo2Service(..., _permissionService, ...);

    // Act

    // Assert
    HttpStatusException exceptionThrown = await Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync<HttpStatusException>(async () => await myService.GetFileByObjectId(It.IsAny<int>()));
    Assert.IsTrue(exceptionThrown.CustomErrorCode == 23);
```

How can bypass `SelectFoo2` method (asking for connection string)?
It's a method belongs to `Foo2Service` and not another injected service.

**EDIT**: The `SelectFoo2` method (I don't want test query execution)

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Foo2>> SelectFoo2(int objectId)
{
    // Query sql using RepoDB

    return await ExecuteQueryAsync<EcmObject>(sql, param);
}
```

And the `ExecuteQueryAsync` method from the `BaseService`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteQueryAsync<T>(string sql, Dictionary<string, object> param)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_ecmCommonInfoService.ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        IEnumerable<T> records = await connection.ExecuteQueryAsync<T>(sql, param);

        return records;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you know the problem is with SelectFoo2 but you didn't post it?   You will have to mock out the bit where SelectFoo2 gets the connection string.

Comment: With constrained frameworks like Moq, NSubstitute, FakeItEasy you can mock only virtual members. If you want mock non-virtual members you should use unconstrained tools such as TypeMock, JustMock, MS Fakes, Prig, Ionad.Fody, AutoFake, Unmockable, Harmony, MethodRedirect, Pose, Shimmy.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new. I can't understand

Answer (score 0):

**Unit test** is telling you to change your implementation because it can't be tested. If you can not unit test your code there is a **code smell**.

Few recommendations I would suggest to make programming life less stressful.

- Use **Design Pattern** and **Design Principle** as a guide. For design principles, start with **SOLID principles**.
- Program in interface not implementation (This will help you during unit test)

Going back to your problem. Better to put `ExecuteQueryAsync` in separate class with interface. Then, do the **dependency injection** by injecting the interface.

Now you can stab the `ExecuteQueryAsync` without forcing you to connect in SQL.

Comment: I don't want to test DAL tier. Maybe you mean move `SelectFoo2` in another class (but I won't have so many classes)